# what tools use for GUI/functional testing of Eclipse RCP apps?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

We are developing RCP Eclipse based application,currently for functional/GUI tests we use RCPTT tool although we are not fully satisfied with it.

What are the other options beside SwtBot for GUI testing (on multiplatform Linux/Windows)? Abby,TFTP,Jubula are discontinued or not maintained any more.

Comment: Could you list some of the reasons why you are not satisfied with RCPTT? And could you share some details about the application? I've worked with Jubula, RCPTT and SwtBot so far, each of them has pros and cons.

Comment: We observe instability in "stable" tests from time to time - RCPTT sometimes does not see GUI element although it is present on screen - this relates to default Eclipse elements. Most of the times waits/try is a workaround but not always works. There was increase time in opening text editor from Eclipse Mars to newer (Neon,Oxygen) - additional 15-20 sec at least once per test which contributes tu dozen of minutes longer for whole test run (this is visible only with rcptt+aut test,no issue while using app), no support for parallel test execution so it had to be done by scripts,hacks,jobs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since i cannot write a comment yet:

Jubula is still in development and maintained[git repository](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jubula/org.eclipse.jubula.core.git/). Bugs are fixed and new Features are implemented. The last release was from may 2017 but the next release is planned before eastern 2018.

The Jubula ITE(Integrated Testing Environment) can be used or the newer Java API in which you also could write tests with java.